# Анимация border-radius в Firefox работает неправильно

Tags: html, css

Сделал анимацию округления квадрата, в хроме работает, а фаерфокс округляет только когда я переключаюсь между вкладками. Сам квадрат крутится, но не округляется. Спросил у знакомых, в итоге у пары человек все нормально, а у других такая же проблема. Префиксы не решили проблему.

```css
@keyframes turning {
  0% {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    border-radius: 50% 0 0 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: violet;
  margin: 100px;
  animation: turning 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WVZdpa)

Comment: У меня на linux и в хроме и лисе все работает....

Comment: А если в div изначально добавить `border-radius: 0;`  ?

Comment: У кого-то работает, а у кого-то криво. Пытаюсь разобраться в чем проблема. попробывал задать border-radius: 0Ю не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файрфоксе какай-то баг, ибо анимация у вас нормальная.
Не знаю причины и механизма этого бага, но он явно связан с каким-то особенностями пересчета.

Я заметил, что если в анимацию добавить еще одно свойство, например, хорошо отличающийся фоновый цвет,

```
0% {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  background-color:#000;      
}
```

то в файрфоксе начинает нормально отрабатывать и анимация скругления. Если цвет отличается незначительно, то анимация отрабатывает рывками или не работает вообще.

Воспользуйтесь таким вот костылем с цветом, а в ФФ походу нужно репортить баг.

Comment: У меня нормально заработало только когда почистил фаерфокс. Из-за чего проблема, осталось для меня загадкой.

Comment: Я зарепортил баг в Мозиллу, вроде подтвердили. По крайней мере, не отклонен =) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1571478

Answer (score 1):

Ну что, прошло почти ровно три года и этот  баг таки вроде пофиксили:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1571478

> Mayank Bansal
>
> Comment 4 • 9 hours ago
>
> Testcase works fine on Nightly now
>
> Status: NEW → RESOLVED
>
> Closed: 9 hours ago
>
> Resolution: --- → WORKSFORME